# Update a single value in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

My goal is to update the `fontFamily` value but retain the `boxShadow` and `opacity` values when sending a dispatch to the reducer.

Here is my initial state inside of my reducer:

```js
// set theme
  theme: {
    
    fontFamily: "",
    boxShadow: "90%",
    opacity: "100%",
  },
```

```js
 case "SET_THEME":
      return {
        ...state,
        theme: action.item,
      };
```

Now, I want to update the `fontFamily` value and keep all of the other values the same.

Each time I dispatch this action, the values are overwritten:

```js
dispatch({
        type: "SET_THEME",
        item: {
          buttonTextColor: e.target.value,
        },
      });
```

Any ideas how I can retain the values already stored in my initial state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following in your reducer

```
 case "SET_THEME":
      return {
        ...state,
        theme: {
          ...state.theme,
          ...action.item,
        }
      };
```

This will spread the `state.theme` and `action.item` into the theme object, letting you having the remaining state theme values and the new action item ones

Answer (score 0):

use the spread operator to keep the old keys of the object and overwrite only what you want :

```
case "SET_THEME":
  return {
    ...state,
    theme: {
      ...state.theme,
      fontFamily: action.item.fontFamily
    },
  };
```